# What coordinates Field Calculator used when given $x to get X coordinate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, field-calculator, xy

I have a shapefile that I have saved in EPSG:3879 (.prj file shows that) and current CRS of the project has been set to EPSG:3879. Still when I used Field Calculator command $x to get X coordinates for points, it does not use that EPSG:3879 coordinates but seemingly EPSG:3067 (that some other shapefiles in the same project use).

How can I get coordinates in EPSG:3879?

Comment: Interesting, which QGIS version and platform are you using? Does it work if you remove this _other_ shapefile from the project beforehand?

Comment: It should use the files CRS.

Comment: Does your Shapefile have **.qpj** file as well? If so, QGIS ignores **.prj**.

Comment: What happens if you load that shp into a blank QGIS project and try the calculation?

Comment: As @Vesanto suggested, I tested the issue in several ways, and in the end, it confirms that Field Calculator will use the file's CRS. To get your values in other formats, you likely have to reproject your shapefile before doing the calculations. You can always copy back (join?) the coordinates in your first shapefile.

Answer (score 11):

The QGIS field calculator is pretty powerful. So since the file is in EPSG:3879, it will report x and y in EPSG:3879.

I don't quite understand why you think it is reporting in EPSG:3067, perhaps you re-projected the file incorrectly at some stage.

But you can get co-ordinates in EPSG:4326 (lat, lon) by re-project  within the field calculator.

So for X:

```
X( transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:3879', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

For Y:

```
Y( transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:3879', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on the answer of @heikkivesanto, the expression can be made more generic as follows:

```
x( transform( $geometry, layer_property(@layer_id, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

This removes the need to copy in / remember the EPSG code for the layer CRS.

Further still:

```
x( transform( $geometry ,  layer_property(  @layer_id ,'crs'), @project_crs ) )
```

Uses the project CRS as the output, instead of hard coding to WGS84.